# Why is SED not accepting my input?

Tags: unix, sed, user-input

Hi I'm new to unix and trying to make a script that removes punctuation from user input using SED. But it isn't working.

```sh
read -p "Please enter a word or sentence: " word
sed -n 's/[^a-zA-Z ]//g' $word
```

if i enter abcd.,abcd it will give me an error
"sed: can't read abcd,.abcd: No such file or directory"

So I guess that means it is treating the variable $word as a file instead of a string that I want it to process.

How would I fix this?

Comment: I think you should read something about pipes and stdin\stdout. You need to pipe read output to sed input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` treat argument as input-file.

Try following instead:

```
echo "$word" | sed -n 's/[^a-z]//ig'
```

Comment: I realised I typed something wrong in my original script.
It shouldh have been `sed 's/[^a-zA-Z ]//g'`.

But the echo "$word" has fixed my original problem thank you

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (bash):

```
sed 's/[^a-zA-Z ]//g' <<<"$word"
```

This utilizes the `here-string` in bash.